# true/false of an inequality

Tags: simplifying-expressions, inequalities

I would like to check whether the expression is always positive or not with certain assumptions on variables. I have tried this approach but it doesn't solve the purpose. Any other way to resolve this?

```
Assuming[{1> a > 0.5, x > 0, y > 0}, 
Resolve[(2 a Log[1 + (1 + y)/(a x)])/(1 + y) - 
2 a Log[1 + 1/(a x + y)] + (
2 (-1 + a - y) Log[1 + 1/(x - (a x)/(1 + y))])/(
1 + y) + (1 - a + (1 + x + y + a (-1 + (-2 + a) x + y))/
   Sqrt[-4 a x (1 + x) + (1 + x + a x + y)^2]) Log[
  1 + 2/(-1 + x - a x - y + 
    Sqrt[-4 a x (1 + x) + (1 + x + a x + y)^2])] + (-1 + a + (
   1 + x + y + a (-1 + (-2 + a) x + y))/
   Sqrt[-4 a x (1 + x) + (1 + x + a x + y)^2]) Log[
  1 + 2/(-1 + (-1 + a) x + y + 
    Sqrt[-4 a x (1 + x) + (1 + x + a x + y)^2])] > 0]]
```

Mathematica gives the same expression as a result. I guess it's not working because of so many Log! Any suggestions?

Comment: `Resolve` is not the correct function for this. `Resolve` is for dealing with `ForAll` and `Exists` quantifiers. Try `Reduce` instead.

Comment: doesn't help. It's giving the same expression as a result.

Answer (score 3):

Two issues:

1) Generally speaking, functions which don't take an Assumptions option will ignore Assuming and $Assumptions.  Neither Resolve nor Reduce take assumptions.

2) Resolve is for quantifier elimination.

This problem can be easily cast as a quantifier problem without assumptions by introducing a ForAll with the conditions you're using as assumptions:

```
Resolve[
   ForAll[
      {a,x,y},
      a > 0.5 && x > 0 && y > 0,
      (2 a Log[1+(1+y)/(a x)])/(1+y)-2 a Log[1+1/(a x+y)]+(2 (-1+a-y) Log[1+1/(x-(a x)/(1+y))])/(1+y)+(1-a+(1+x+y+a (-1+(-2+a) x+y))/Sqrt[-4 a x (1+x)+(1+x+a x+y)^2]) Log[1+2/(-1+x-a x-y+Sqrt[-4 a x (1+x)+(1+x+a x+y)^2])]+(-1+a+(1+x+y+a (-1+(-2+a) x+y))/Sqrt[-4 a x (1+x)+(1+x+a x+y)^2]) Log[1+2/(-1+(-1+a) x+y+Sqrt[-4 a x (1+x)+(1+x+a x+y)^2])]>0
   ]
 ]
```

Now, whether this quantifier elimination can be done in finite time (these algorithms are "doubly exponential" in their complexity) is another question.  I got bored after a minute or two.

Comment: `Resolve[ForAll[{a, x, y}, a > 0.5 && x > 0 && y > 0, x + y + a > 0]]` works, suggesting the complicated inequality will be resolved too

Comment: Thanks Itai for your answer. I hope there could be a way to know how much time it's going to take.

Answer (score 1):

When we carefully look at the expression under consideration
$$\frac{2 a \log \left(\frac{y+1}{a x}+1\right)}{y+1}-2 a \log \left(\frac{1}{a x+y}+1\right)+\frac{2 (a-y-1) \log \left(\frac{1}{x-\frac{a x}{y+1}}+1\right)}{y+1}+\left(\frac{a ((a-2) x+y-1)+x+y+1}{\sqrt{(a x+x+y+1)^2-4 a x (x+1)}}-a+1\right) \log \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{(a x+x+y+1)^2-4 a x (x+1)}-a x+x-y-1}+1\right)+\left(\frac{a ((a-2) x+y-1)+x+y+1}{\sqrt{(a x+x+y+1)^2-4 a x (x+1)}}+a-1\right) \log \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{(a x+x+y+1)^2-4 a x (x+1)}+(a-1) x+y-1}+1\right),  $$
 we will see $$x-\frac{a x}{y+1} $$ as one of the denominators. It's quite clear that the term with it takes negative values:

```
FindInstance[1/ (x - (a x)/(1 + y)) + 1 < 0 && a > 1/2 && x > 0 && y > 0 && 

 a <= 3 && x <= 3 && y <= 3, {a, x, y}, Reals]
```

> {{{a -> 5/2, x -> 2, y -> 1}}}

In this case its logarithm is not defined over the reals. Therefore, the claim is not true.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @user64494. I forgot to add the correct constraint. "a" is the transmissivity of a beam-splitter, and we would like it to be between 0.5-1. So this problem wouldn't occur because a can't be 5/2...